# Spring integration project with spring MVC

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to integrate spring MVC(REST) layer with Spring Integration Layer, there would be to and fro traffic. I want the spring integration layer to be used by several other services too. So, the spring integration code has to be a independent jar. How should I be implementing it.
1) Create Pom dependency for SI project in the MVC  project.
2) SI project to be running on the server. The SI and MVC can be on same server or different servers.(http calls)

Would prefer to do the 1) way. Where the SI project jar is created as a dependency.
 How can this be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very common pattern; just add the SI dependencies to the POM and invoke the SI flow from your controller using a [Messaging Gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway).